# When is a sufficient statistic also complete?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

A sufficient statistic $T$ for the parameter $\theta$ is said to be complete if and only if: $$ E(g(T)) = 0 \ \  \forall \theta \Leftrightarrow g(T) = 0$$

Then it's said that a vector$\mathbf{T}$ with length $k$ of sufficient statistics is complete if they are in a k-dimensional rectangle.

I didn't get the last paragraph. Why is it said so? Could you give me an example to illustrate that?

Thank you! :)

Comment: If $T=(T_1,T_2,\ldots,T_k)$ is a k-dimensional sufficient statistic for some parameter $\theta$, then to check if $T$ is complete or not, we have the definition of completeness as you stated above. Other than that, if in particular, we are working with a distribution in the exponential family, then we can often conclude sufficiency and completeness of the same statistic together.

Comment: Take a random sample $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution where both parameters are unknown. Then it is true that $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=(\overline X,S^2)$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta=(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: @stubbornatom ter, but I mean, why do we check it this way? How is it a consequence of $E(g(T))=0 \Leftrightarrow g(T)=0$?

Comment: @M.Gonzalez I don't understand your question. What is $k$? For $N(\theta,\theta^2)$, statistic $(X,X^2)$ is sufficient and it is in a two-dim rectangle but $(X,X^2)$ is not complete for $\theta$.